# How to Convert NSString into CGPoint in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am getting the values from UITextfield into NSString , need to convert the values of NSString into CGPoint,  Suppose if i enter 6,5 into textfield it should covert it into CGPoint.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

See [CGPointFromString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPointFromString) (documentation in link). The string has to be in the format `{x,y}` so you would need to add those to the user input yourself:

```
CGPoint myPoint = CGPointFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"{%@}",textField.text]);
```

Will return CGPointZero if the string is invalid.