# Converting a CGPoint from a Plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, plist, scene

I'm working in Spritekit and I'm pretty new to it. I'm creating a game with levels and for each level I'm trying to position the sprites in my game to be proportionate to the screen size. I'm calling their positions from plist files. Since I am positioning each sprite according to the screen's dimensions and size, I would have to position it something like this

```
Sprite.position = CGPointMake(self.scene.size.width /2, self.scene.size.height /2);
```

My question is, how would I be able to convert this position from my plist? I tried using

```
Sprite.position = CGPointFromString(level[@"Sprite"]);
```

and typing

```
CGPointMake(self.scene.size.width /2, self.scene.size.height /2);
```

in my plist file, but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you access  data from a plist:

```
NSString* path = [[ NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString* finalPath = [ path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyGameData.plist"];
NSDictionary *plistData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];
```

The simplest way would probably be to store the x and y positions in 2 separate strings. Something like PlayerPositionX and PlayerPositionY

Then you convert the string to a float like this:

```
float myFloat = [myString floatValue];
```

You can also convert a single string into a CGPoint like this:

```
CGPoint myPoint = CGPointFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"{%@}",textField.text]);
```

The string has to be in the format {x,y}

(Credit to jrturton for his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978518/how-to-convert-nsstring-into-cgpoint-in-iphone)).

Answer (score 0):

You could solve the problem of positioning your sprites proportionate to the screen size in the following way:

First you create your plist like this:

```
Sprite = {
   x = 20;
   y = 20;
}
```

Then you can obviously get the values with:

```
NSDictionary *spriteInfo = plist[@"Sprite"];
NSNumber *xPosition = spriteInfo[@"x"];
NSNumber *yPosition = spriteInfo[@"y"];
```

Now you can interpret these values in two ways:

- They represent the position your sprite should be on a default screen (ex: 320x568) and you get the actual position with:

  ```
  actionPosition = xPosition * screenSize / defaultScreenSize;
  //ex: 40 = 20 * 640 / 320, if the current device has a width of 640.
  ```
- Or the represent % values, aka the sprite should be at 20% of the screen, thus you'd get the actual position with:

  ```
   actionPosition = screenSize * xPosition / 100;
  //ex: 128 = 20 * 640 / 100, if the current device has a width of 640.
  ```